# How to apply a function on specified parts of a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm completely new to R, and ran into some problems during an online R course. I have a folder with 332 csv files, named 001-332. The task is to write a function, that gives the number of complete cases for every file in a given range and the id for each file (i.e. function(directory, id), where directory is the folder with the files, and id is a vector specifying which files to use). The output should look like this: https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/rprog%2Fdoc%2Fcomplete-demo.html

I managed to create a dataframe that contains all data from the files specified by the id argument.

```
complete <- function(directory, id=1:332){
  files <- list.files(directory, full.names=T)
  dat <- data.frame()
  for(i in id){
    dat<-rbind(dat, read.csv(files[i]))
  }
}
```

After this I tried to use the complete.cases function on the dat dataset (of course inside my function) by `sum(complete.cases(dat))`, but this clearly gives the sum of complete cases for the whole "dat" dataframe. My problem is, that I should get the sum of complete cases for each id seperately. I'm experimenting for hours now with many subsetting solution, but can't find a way to do this. Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After creating a couple of files in the working directory,

```
 list.files(pattern="^file\\d+")
 #[1] "file1.txt" "file2.txt"

 sapply(files, function(x) {x1 <- read.csv(x, header=TRUE, sep="")
                               sum(complete.cases(x1))})

 # file1.txt file2.txt 
 #  1          4
```

You could also change the function

```
 complete <- function(directory, id=1:2, pat='^file\\d+'){
    files <- list.files(directory, pattern=pat, full.names=TRUE)
    v1 <- vector("numeric", length(files))
    for(i in seq_along(id)){
    v1[i] <- sum(complete.cases(read.csv(files[i], sep='')))
      }
   data.frame(id=id, nobs=v1)
   }

  complete(directory, id=1:2)
  #  id nobs
  #1  1    1
  #2  2    4
```

#### Update

You could also make the function to read the files based on specific pattern of the `id`

```
 complete <- function(directory, id=1:2){
   fileLook <- paste0("file", sprintf('%03d', id)) 
   Allfiles <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)
   files <- grep(paste(fileLook, collapse="|"), Allfiles, value=TRUE)
   library(gtools)
   files <- mixedsort(files)  
   v1 <- vector("numeric", length(files))
     for(i in seq_along(id)){
       v1[i] <- sum(complete.cases(read.csv(files[i], sep='')))

        }
     data.frame(id=id, nobs=v1)
  }



 complete(directory, 1:2)
 #  id nobs
 #1  1    1
 #2  2    4
 complete(directory, c(1,3))
 #  id nobs
 #1  1    1
 #2  3    6
```